# What is the meaning of 尔毋从从尔。

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was looking up the meaning of 尔 and found this:

尔毋从从尔。《礼记·檀弓》

Can I translate 尔毋从从尔 as "This doesn't follow that"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 爾毋從從爾

read it as:

you (爾 —-> 汝) don’t (毋) [make you hairstyle] big & high (從從 —-> 大高)! (爾)

the last “爾” is a modal particle

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=9618#s10045202

have fun :)

Comment: I'm unclear about the woman's name. Is her name mentioned?

Comment: @Pedroski, no lah  the book “禮記注疏” 卷六 page 58 just mentioned this lady as  “the daughter of confucius’s elder brother” (孔子兄女) https://archive.org/details/06081218.cn/page/n57/mode/1up

Comment: Oh well, not important! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`尔毋从从尔` 出自《礼记·檀弓》

> 南官之妻之姑之丧，夫子诲之髽曰："**尔毋从从尔**！尔毋扈扈尔！盖榛以为笄，长尺，而总八寸."

意思是

> 南宫绦妻子的婆婆死后，孔子教她做丧髻的方法说："**你不必将丧髻做得太高**，也不必做得很大。用榛木做簪子，其长一尺；束发的布条垂下后有八寸长即可."

`你不必将丧髻做得太高` translate to English is `You don't have to make your bun too high.`.